# Proof that $\sum_{k = 0}^{N-1} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{N} \left( k + \frac{1}{2} \right) \right) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series

I have come across the expression

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1} \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi}{N}\left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right) $$

and I happened to notice that it equals $0$ for all integer values of $N > 1$. This it very easy to prove for $N$ even, by noticing some symmetries in the angles that appear in the arguments of the cosines. This does not work for $N$ odd. When trying to prove it for $N$ odd, I split it as

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1} \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi}{N}\left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{N} \right)\sum_{k = 0}^{N-1} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{N}k\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{N} \right)\sum_{k = 0}^{N-1} \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{N}k\right)$$

and noticed (by checking it numerically) that the two terms are individually $0$ for all integer $N > 1$

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{N-1} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{N}k\right) = 0 = \sum_{k = 0}^{N-1} \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{N}k\right).$$

From here I don't know to proceed. I have thought of applying some ideas from Fourier series, maybe thinking of the sums as the series of a function evaluated at $x = 1$, but I've got nothing concrete.

*How to prove the statement for $N$ odd?*
*Or even better, how to prove it for generic $N$?*

Comment: Are you open to proofs using complex numbers? If so, take the real part of the sum of the roots of $z^N+1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You face [sums of sines and cosines of angles in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro)
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{N-p} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{N}k\right) =\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{N}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi -2 \pi 
   p}{N}\right)\right)$$
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{N-p} \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{N}k\right) =\frac{1}{2} \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{N}\right) \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi  (N+1-2
   p)}{N}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{N}\right)\right)$$